# xapian problems - 32-bit C# windows

Tags: c#, .net, database, indexing, xapian

with regards to [How to compile and use Xapian on Windows with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/XapianUnderWindows.aspx). I have the same problem but I am running a 32-bit windows and my platform is set to run on x86 also. what can I do?

i also am not able to reference zlib1.dll, every time I try it tells me it is not a valid COM or assemly. I am using visual studio 2010

any suggestions, for those of you who have tried it out? or perhaps know of such an error: The type initializer for 'Xapian.Xapian' threw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compile Xapian for Win32 - there are prebuilt binaries available at http://www.flax.co.uk/xapian_binaries for C#. If this doesn't solve your problem please let me know via that website (or better, via the xapian-discuss mailing list at http://xapian.org/lists where there are a lot more people who might be able to help).